# date beamer metropolis using rmarkdown

Tags: beamer, header-footer, date, beamer-metropolis, rmarkdown

I am trying to make a beamer presentation with the Metropolis theme. I adapted the colors like this:

```
    output: 
        beamer_presentation:
            latex_engine: xelatex
            theme: "metropolis"
            slide_level: 3
    navigation: horizontal 
    classoption: "aspectratio=169"
    header-includes:
         - \metroset{block=fill}
         - \useoutertheme{infolines}
         - \usepackage{xcolor}
         - \definecolor{GreenM}{RGB}{107, 169, 36}
         - \definecolor{BlueM}{RGB}{6, 48, 96}
         - \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=BlueM}
         - \setbeamercolor{title separator}{fg = GreenM}
         - \setbeamercolor{author}{fg=BlueM}
         - \setbeamercolor{date}{fg=BlueM}
         - \setbeamercolor{progress bar in section page}{fg = GreenM,bg = gray}
 
         - \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=GreenM, fg = white}
         - \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=BlueM}
         - \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=BlueM}
         - \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=GreenM}
         - \setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=red}
         - \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=BlueM, bg=white}
         - \setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=BlueM}
         - \setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=BlueM}
         - \setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=BlueM}
         - \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
```

Now the date is displayed as 2022/2023. I want to set this to "May 27, 2023" (which is not the date of today) on the title slide and in the footer. I am making this presentation using Rmarkdown. Does someone knows how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `\AtBeginDocument{\date{May 27, 2023}}` in your header includes:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
output: 
    beamer_presentation:
        latex_engine: xelatex
        theme: "moloch" # modern fork of the metropolis theme
        slide_level: 3
navigation: horizontal 
classoption: "aspectratio=169"
header-includes:
      - \useoutertheme{infolines}
      - \usepackage{xcolor}
      - \definecolor{GreenM}{RGB}{107, 169, 36}
      - \definecolor{BlueM}{RGB}{6, 48, 96}
      - \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=BlueM}
      - \setbeamercolor{title separator}{fg = GreenM}
      - \setbeamercolor{author}{fg=BlueM}
      - \setbeamercolor{date}{fg=BlueM}
      - \setbeamercolor{progress bar in section page}{fg = GreenM,bg = gray}

      - \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=GreenM, fg = white}
      - \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=BlueM}
      - \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=BlueM}
      - \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=GreenM}
      - \setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=red}
      - \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=BlueM, bg=white}
      - \setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=BlueM}
      - \setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=BlueM}
      - \setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=BlueM}
      - \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
      - \AtBeginDocument{\date{May 27, 2023}}
---
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Marie You're welcome!